# Error: Unsupported operation: StdIOUtils._getStdioInputStream

Tags: flutter, dart, console

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('Enter the first integer:');
  int? first = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

  print('Enter the second integer:');
  int? second = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

  if (first == second) {
    print('The two integers are equal.');
  } else {
    print('The two integers are not equal.');
  }
}
```

This is my Dart Code trying to practice simple operation of the language, I am using IntelliJ and Android Studio both the console said it is read only cannot take my keyboard input, please resolve this. Many thanks.

I wish I could run the program.

Answer (score 0):

`stdin.readLineSync()` is used with encoding, it's a CLI command